# App failing to run in VS Code (iOS simulator)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

I been trying to run my app in IOS Simulator in VS Code. When I type Flutter Run, it's starts Xcode builds but the it fails to build in IOS.

Error is as follows-

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
MacBook-Pro:footballcrazy appleuser$ flutter clean
Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                      1,964ms
Deleting build...                                                    3ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                               0ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       0ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         0ms
MacBook-Pro:footballcrazy appleuser$ flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in footballcrazy...                    1,995ms
MacBook-Pro:footballcrazy appleuser$ flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             13.7s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           153.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/7f/vrh09tld72ngmdfm94b1tpp80000gn/T/flutter_tools.AxRTm0/flutter_ios_build_temp_
        dirXC4DET/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCust
    omBrowser.m:148:42: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];
                                             ^~~~~~~
                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1
    : note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0))
    NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCust
    omBrowser.m:156:61: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      BOOL openedInBrowser = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                                ^~~~~~~
                                                                openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1
    : note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0))
    NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:5
    3:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *_authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    5:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthentica
    tionSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:1
    43:7: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC =
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    5:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthentica
    tionSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:1
    44:37: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              [[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL
                                        ^~~~~
                                        ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    5:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthentica
    tionSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:1
    80:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                             ^~~~~~~
                                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1
    : note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0))
    NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    03:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC = _authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    5:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthentica
    tionSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    5 warnings generated.
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCust
    omBrowser.m:148:42: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];
                                             ^~~~~~~
                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1
    : note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0))
    NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCust
    omBrowser.m:156:61: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      BOOL openedInBrowser = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                                ^~~~~~~
                                                                openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1
    : note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0))
    NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:5
    3:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *_authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    5:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthentica
    tionSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:1
    43:7: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC =
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    5:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthentica
    tionSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:1
    44:37: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              [[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL
                                        ^~~~~
                                        ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    5:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthentica
    tionSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:1
    80:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                             ^~~~~~~
                                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1
    : note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url
    API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0))
    NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    03:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC = _authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:2
    5:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthentica
    tionSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated
    here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    5 warnings generated.
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4
    .1.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:101:72: warning: sending 'FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin
    *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull'
        [[FLTFirebasePluginRegistry sharedInstance] registerFirebasePlugin:self];
                                                                           ^~~~
    In module 'firebase_core' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4
    .1.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2
    .1.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h:23:64: note: passing argument to parameter
    'firebasePlugin' here
    - (void)registerFirebasePlugin:(id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull)firebasePlugin;
                                                                   ^
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4
    .1.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:1905:45: warning: 'keyWindow' is deprecated: first
    deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as
    it returns a key window across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
                                                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:5
    1: note: property 'keyWindow' is declared deprecated here
    @property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used
    for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected
    scenes", ios(2.0, 13.0));
                                                      ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:5
    1: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4
    .1.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:101:72: warning: sending 'FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin
    *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull'
        [[FLTFirebasePluginRegistry sharedInstance] registerFirebasePlugin:self];
                                                                           ^~~~
    In module 'firebase_core' imported from
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4
    .1.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2
    .1.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h:23:64: note: passing argument to parameter
    'firebasePlugin' here
    - (void)registerFirebasePlugin:(id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull)firebasePlugin;
                                                                   ^
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4
    .1.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:1905:45: warning: 'keyWindow' is deprecated: first
    deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as
    it returns a key window across all connected scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
                                                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy/ios/Pods/Target Support
    Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:5
    1: note: property 'keyWindow' is declared deprecated here
    @property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used
    for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected
    scenes", ios(2.0, 13.0));
                                                      ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/i
    PhoneSimulator16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:5
    1: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore
    -4.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:457:29: warning: comparison of distinct
    pointer types ('FIRQuery *' and 'NSNull * _Nonnull') [-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
      if (query == nil || query == [NSNull null]) {
                          ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/appleuser/edgamble/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore
    -4.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:457:29: warning: comparison of distinct
    pointer types ('FIRQuery *' and 'NSNull * _Nonnull') [-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
      if (query == nil || query == [NSNull null]) {
                          ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    No file or variants found for asset: assets/covers.
    Failed to package /Users/appleuser/footballcrazy.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every
    build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output
    dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based
    on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every
    build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output
    dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based
    on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every
    build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output
    dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based
    on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does
    not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script
    phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in
    the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does
    not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script
    phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in
    the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every
    build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output
    dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based
    on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Libuv-gRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every
    build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output
    dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based
    on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/7f/vrh09tld72ngmdfm94b1tpp80000gn/T/flutter_tools.AxRTm0/flutter_ios_build_temp_
        dirXC4DET/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

Pubspec.yaml-

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.2 <3.3.6"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  sign_in_with_apple: ^4.1.0
  crypto: ^3.0.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.2.1
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  provider: ^6.0.4
  rxdart: ^0.27.5
  json_annotation: ^4.7.0
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

  build_runner: ^2.3.2
  json_serializable: ^6.5.4
```

I would appreciate feedback and can give further information if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please Do Change the `deployment_target = '11.0'` to `deployment_target = '14.0'` in the `podfile` inside the
`ios`

Comment: I have done this and has made no difference. Issue seems to be a lot of outdated Pods on Xcode. Doing an app after using a Flutter Course by Fireship